# Drop Down Menus in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, navigation

I am trying to enable Drop Down Menus in SharePoint Online by enabling structural navigation as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn850367)

However the top link bar Site items do not display any subsites as dropdowns? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you enabled show subsites under `Global Navigation` -> `Structural Navigation` -> `Show subsites`?

Answer (score 1):

> It would be nice, if you tried to understand how this structure behaves.

This is complex, try go step by step:

1. Site collection or Root Site:

   ```
   Site Setting -> Navigation -> Check Structural Navigation -> Check Show Subsites -> and click button OK.
   ```
2. Sub site of site collection(or root site):

   ```
   Site Setting -> Navigation -> Check Display the same navigation items as the parent site -> Check Show subsites -> and click button OK.
   ```
3. childs of subsite of Site Collection:

   ```
   Site Setting -> Navigation -> Check Display the same navigation items as the parent site -> Check Show subsites -> and click button OK.
   ```
4. Childs Recursive All

   ```
   Site Setting -> Navigation -> Check Display the same navigation items as the parent site -> Check Show subsites -> and click button OK.
   ```

See example of result:

[image: Image Navigation]

Hope this help.

Comment: I have exactly OP's problem but this solution doesn't work. Presumably Microsoft has changed something between 2014 and now...